# Restoring SQL Server backup with different block sizes

Tags: sql-server, size, block

I am trying to set up a new server that is using iscsi for the storage of the SQL Server data. When I try to restore to the new setup, it tells me it can due to the block size being different with the old being 512 and the new at 64k or 8192 (this depends on how the iSCSI is created and 8192 is the smallest I can get it).

Basically, it is the same question as this but the suggestion didn't work.

[Restore-SqlDatabase using a backup with a different sector size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57090413/restore-sqldatabase-using-a-backup-with-a-different-sector-size)

Any ideas on how I can get this working?

Steps in the linked article above and lots of google searching

The error I am getting either by restoring with the UI or the PowerShell command is as follows:
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: Cannot restore the file '' because it was originally written with sector size 512. 'E:\data\myTestDB.mdf' is not on a device with sector size 8192. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

I have tried this in the SQL Query per that article and some others I have found:

```
$DatabaseServer = "localhost" 
$DatabaseName = "myDB" 
$BackupFilePath = "\\10.1.11.77\DatabaseStaging\myDB.bak" 
$RelocateData = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile, $assemblySqlServerSmoExtendedFullName"('myTestDB', 'E:\data\myTestDB.mdf') 
$RelocateLog = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile, $assemblySqlServerSmoExtendedFullName"('myTestDB_Log', 'E:\data\myTestDB.ldf') 

$relocate=@($RelocateData,$RelocateLog) 

Restore-SqlDatabase -BlockSize 8192 -ServerInstance $DatabaseServer -Database $DatabaseName -RelocateFile $relocate -BackupFile $BackupFilePath -RestoreAction Database 

or 

Restore-SqlDatabase -BlockSize 512 -ServerInstance $DatabaseServer -Database $DatabaseName -RelocateFile $relocate -BackupFile $BackupFilePath -RestoreAction Database
```

Comment: What is the actual full and complete error message you get - as text, not screen shot(s).

Comment: It's simple: Execute Restore

Comment: First: Execute RESTORE HEADERONLY to check what is the block size and then execute

Comment: Then execute RESTORE DB in order to restore db

Comment: Using the real block size

Comment: RESTORE https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-headeronly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: It might be helpful if you post actually queries you're running as well as the errors you're getting

Comment: @BogdanSahlean I added the statement I used and the specific error to the question.